# User "nobody" keeps showing on the user list after being excluding some users

Tags: gdm, users

I did some googling but there were people with same problem(more on why than problem)

But nothing explains reason why "nobody" shows up after excluding some users from login screen user list. I can simply exclude nobody by editing custom.conf but what is the reason for nobody showing up?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? What architecture? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: User "nobody" was invented by NFS (Network File System) - it's an unprivileged, system special userid that does nothing. If a remote NFS client send in a request with an unknown UID (unknown on the server, known on the client), the server uses "nobody"'s UID instead. Did you see the line in /etc/passwd?     $ grep nobody /etc/passwd  
  nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh  In an 18-bit field, it's -2, easy to detect

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)